# How to properly use tf.data for training Keras models in tensorflow v2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I'm unclear on how to optimally use tf.data for training Keras models in tensorflow v2:

I've taken the following approach:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("filename.tfrecords").shuffle(total_size)
validation_size = int(validation_size_split_ratio * total_size)

validation_dataset = dataset.take(validation_size)
validation_dataset = validation_dataset.map(preprocess_function, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
validation_dataset = validation_dataset.shuffle(validation_size)
# validation_dataset = validation_dataset.cache()
# validation_dataset = validation_dataset.repeat()
validation_dataset = validation_dataset.batch(batch_size)
validation_dataset = validation_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

train_dataset = dataset.skip(validation_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(preprocess_function, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(total_size - validation_size)
# train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat()
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

where the dataset is defined to take one full pass through all the data, and then stop (i.e. reach the end). Please note that all the repeat operations have been commented out. The model would be trained as follows:

```
training_history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=validation_dataset, epochs=epochs)
```

in this case each epoch would correspond to a new pass through the entire dataset object. Alternatively, we could uncomment the "repeat" statements above and then train the model like so:

```
training_history = model.fit(train_dataset, steps_per_epoch=total_size // batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=validation_dataset, validation_steps=500)
```

Which is the optimal approach and why? Should we be using the repeat operations as in the second approach. In practice, I've found the first approach has better training time... but then when should one use the "repeat" operation. There also seems to be a long pause when Keras finishes training the epochs and then runs the validation set. I can literally see the GPU utilization drop from 95% to 0... any suggestions regarding this? Thanks!

Using the first approach above, I also see this message after each epoch:

```
Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while)
```

Does the shuffle buffer need to be refilled after each epoch?

and I also see this, which I don't understand:

```
Encountered a stop event that was not preceded by a start event.
```

In particular, I see the GPU usage utilization drop to 0 after this message